# XmlPullParserException parsing attribute that contains entity

Tags: java, java-me, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser, kxml2

I'm using kXML2 on a legacy JavaME project.
I'm receiving an XML where some attributes contain encoded entites. When I retrieve that attribute value with the call:

```
parser.getAttributeValue
```

It throws an Exception:

```
XmlPullParserException: unresolved
```

I have downloaded the last version of this parser, but it still shows this behavior.

If I remove the problematic line from XML, then there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is what is happening:

The parser must decode entities in attributes, unless you set this property:

```
parser.setFeature(KXmlParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, true);
```

But this implementation throws an exception when that line is called. Allright, so I debugged into the parser source code and I found out that this pull-parser implementation has trouble with entities that are not very common.

So I must inflate the parser entity replacement map with my own "odd" entities for it to work, like this:

```
parser.defineEntityReplacementText("Ntilde", "Ñ");
```

And then everything works fine.